# Calculating an integral depending on a parameter

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have to prove as an excercise of my Measure Theory lessons that for $p > -1$ it is true that: $$\int_0^1 \frac{-\ln(x) x^p}{1-x} dx = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{(n+p)^2}$$

As an advice, the excercise says that there is some series of part of the expression bellow the integral that helps to prove the result. I am trying to use that $x\in (0,1)$ so $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n \geq 0} x^n$. Applying to this excercise we have:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{-\ln(x) x^p}{1-x} dx = \int_0^1 -\ln(x) \cdot \sum_{n \geq 0} x^{n+p} dx = \sum_{n \geq 0} \int_0^1 -\ln(x) \cdot x^{n+p} dx $$

The thing is that the last integral diverges:
$$
\int_0^1 -\ln(x) \cdot x^{n+p}=\left [\dfrac{{x}^{n+p+1}}{(n+p+1)^2}-\dfrac{\left(n+p+1\right)\,{x}^{n+p+1}\,\ln\left(x\right)}{(n+p+1)^2} \right]_{x \rightarrow 0} ^{x=1}
$$
and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \
\ln(x) = -\infty$, so I am getting stuck and do not know how to proceed.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why do you say that the last integral diverges?

Comment: Assuming that $\Re(n+p)>-1$, the integral converges.

Comment: @jwhite i have explained it on a edit

Comment: @AxelT sorry, what does that $R$ mean?

Comment: The second term in the box is a $0\cdot \infty$ indeterminate form. We need L'Hopital's rule to get $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^r \ln(x)=0$ when $r>0$.

Comment: @jwhite you are right, so in fact the integral converges to $\frac{1}{n+p+1}$ and the proof is done. Thanks!